# Parsing for dictionary key values in an array

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, openxml

I have an array that contains details about a form grabbed in open XML. The key format is funky which is why i am having trouble getting the values easily. A simple loop for key, value pairs does not return the data i want. Here is where i am currently at, i am using python3.

```
person = [{'{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}val': 'Title'}, {'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}val': 'FirstName'}, {'{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}val': 'LastName'},{'{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}val': 'Age'}]

for k in person:
   print(k.values())
```

returns

```
dict_values(['Title'])
dict_values(['FirstName'])
dict_values(['LastName'])
dict_values(['Age'])
```

How can i parse these key:value pairs so that i don't get dict_values in front of the value.

Desired output looks like this:

```
Title
FirstName
LastName
Age
```

And if i do this:

```
for k in person:
   for key, value in k:
       print(v)
```

I get returned an error of too many values to unpack, which there is only 2 so i dont understand what the error is. Length is 1 when ran on an individual object

Comment: *The key format is funky*: your XML data uses *namespaces*.

Comment: You are printing the [dictionary view object for the values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). Why are these objects dictionaries with just *one* key-value pair in each?

Comment: Also, `print()` returns `None`, so you are *also* printing `None` after each `dict_values(...)` object.

Comment: @Rakesh: no, because `k.values()` is *not a list*.

Answer (score 0):

You have a rather inefficient format here. You have a list with dictionaries, each with just *one* key-value pair in them. Things would have been a bit better if your code would instead produce a single dictionary with all those key-value pairs in one object.

You are now printing the [`.values()` dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). Each contains just one value. You could loop over the object and print each value of each view:

```
for k in person:
   for value in values():
       print(value)
```

Or you could merge all the dictionaries into one and then just loop directly over the values of that single dictionary:

```
combined = dict(item for d in person for item in d.items())
for value in combined.values():
    print(value)
```